# Why do I have to keep reinstalling Microsoft Access Database Engine in order for my application to run?

Tags: .net, ms-access, database-engine

I have a C# Visual Studio application that I publish and install on a different computer, a Windows 10 64-bit OS, x64-based processor.  The platform target for the build and publish is x64.  The application is actively used and works great for awhile.  Then without warning it gives bizarre database related errors.  I rerun `AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe` and it's fixed.  Why can this be happening, especially now?

Comment: This will be difficult to answer without knowing what the error messages are or the specific version of Microsoft Access Database Engine you're using.  The code/queries that triggers the errors may be helpful, too.

Comment: Perhaps the machine has office x32, and office updates are re-registering the x32 bit version of the database engine. Are you sure the target machine has office x64 installed, or is it running office x32? I suspect that automatic updates to office would also in turn re-register the x32 bit version of the ACE data engine, and that could cause the x64 bit version to become un-registered.

Comment: I have this problem as well, it seems Windows updates keep removing it. Did you have any luck figuring this out? Please write your own answer and accept it so others can learn!